# How can I separate my hex numbers list using backslashes like my image upload?

Tags: python-3.x, hex, separator

I have been working on a little program to print out hex values from 0 to 255 in a format that I havent been able to work out. I'm still learning so I did want advice on how to make this code better and to achieve my results. I have tried to use the join() method to separate each hex value by backslashes but because Im iterating through the lists, each char is being backslashed which isnt what I want. Ive uploaded an image to show how Im looking to output hex values. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

```
hex_chars1 = []
hex_chars2 = []

for i in range(0, 16):
    hex_chars1.append(i)

for j in range(16, 256):
    hex_chars2.append(j)

for char1 in hex_chars1:
    print("x0" + "{0:x}".format(char1))

for char2 in hex_chars2:
    print("x" + "{0:x}".format(char2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generator expression to produce the formatted values then join() them:

```
print(''.join(fr'\x{i:0>2x}' for i in range(256)))
```

Comment: can you please advise me here what the fr'\x{i:0>2x}' part of the print statement does? From what i understand this is the new string format literal syntaxbut what does the r do here? 

Im assuming the i:0>2x is the i value formatted in a 2 character wide hex representation?

Comment: Yes the f means its an f-string and r treats the characters as raw.  Just did that to avoid escaping the backslash.  This should produce the same result: 


print(''.join(f'\\x{i:0>2x}' for i in range(256)))

Answer (score 1):

This should what you want:

```
hex_chars = []

for i in range(0, 256):
    if i <16:
        hex_chars.append("\\x0" + "{0:x}".format(i))
    else:
        hex_chars.append("\\x" + "{0:x}".format(i))

    print(hex_chars[i],end="")

    if (i+1)%16==0:
        print("")
```

Comment: i can follow this code without issue, I just want to confirm what the if statemetnt here does? Is this if the value of i + 1 is modulo by 16? Thanks

Comment: This " if (i+1)%16==0:
        print("") " just for go to new line after every 16 characters printing.